# Cannot format numbers

Tags: java

I am making a calculator but i am struggling to make my numbers round off such as 18.0 to 18. How do i display a number as 18 and not 18.0 for my calculator by formatting it? Here is the code i am using.

```
    String answer;
    double D;
    secondnumber = Double.parseDouble(numTx.getText());

    if (operation.equals("+")) {
        result = firstnum + secondnumber;
        answer = Double.toString(result);
        numTx.setText(answer);
    }
    if (operation.equals("-")) {
        result = firstnum - secondnumber;
        answer = Double.toString(result);
        numTx.setText(answer);
    }
    if (operation.equals("/")) {
        result = firstnum / secondnumber;
        answer = Double.toString(result);
        numTx.setText(answer);
    }
    if (operation.equals("*")) {
        result = firstnum * secondnumber;
        answer = Double.toString(result);
        numTx.setText(answer);
    }
```

above is the code that i tried using but it gave huge errors.
answer = String.format("%1$.1f", result);

Comment: Have you tried to cast the doubles to ints?

Comment: It would be helpful is you showed what you tried and the results.

Comment: Stewart, please improve your question. As you see in the answers, it is not clear if you are interested in rounding of numbers or formatting the output.

Comment: 18.0 == 18 so this is not a rounding issue, it's a display issue. i.e. how you convert a `double` to a String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outputting a `double` value as `18` instead of `18.0` is not *rounding*. That's *formatting*.

Use a [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) and specify the minimum and maximum number of digits you want to see after the decimal point.

Easiest way to create such a `NumberFormat` is to actually create a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Example:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.####"); // show between 0 and 4 decimals, as needed
System.out.println(fmt.format(18.0));    // prints: 18
System.out.println(fmt.format(18.250));  // prints: 18.25
System.out.println(fmt.format(Math.PI)); // prints: 3.1416
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want integer results, you can cast the `double` to an `int` (or `long` if you are expecting large answers). Note: this cast will floor the answer so if you want a more typical rounded result you can use `Math.round()`. To cast a `double` to an `int` you can do this

```
double i = 1.32;
int j = (int) i;
```

Comment: When i try math.round() and round result it wont round it.

Comment: @StewartClay what do you mean it won't round it? How are you calling the function??

Comment: @StewartClay you don't call `Math.round()` and then everything magically is rounded. You need to call `Math.round(18.0)` for example.

Comment: OP doesn't actually want to round to an integer value. OP just want trailing 0 decimals to be removed, as question says: Show `18.0` as `18`.

Comment: @Andreas using a cast or rounding function is, in my opinion, the easiest way to do it without explaining `printf` formatting.

Comment: If `firstnum = 2.0`, `operation = "/"`, and `secondnumber = 5.0`, what do you believe OP is expecting the output to be? Casting/rounding to `int` will output `0`, and I doubt very much that is the expected output. If it was, why do the math using `double` and not `int`? Down-voting answer as not useful, since this is not what OP wants.